# Ubuntu google chrome is showing strange behavior not updating screen since I downloaded docker

Tags: google-chrome, bug-reporting

Since I downloaded docker on my computer I get this strange behavior from chrome when I use it in another workspace. It's not updating the screen properly somehow and it's hard to explain so look it in the gif [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4k7z.gif). I have google-chrome-stable (86.0.4240.75-1) firefox seems fine. My ubuntu is 16.04. Also it's only if it's fullscreen.

**UPDATE: updating my Ubuntu to 18.04 solved the problem. You can also downgrade your version of chrome to a working one as suggested bellow in the answers**

Comment: I have a similar issue.  Waiting for an update.....

Comment: This new version of chrome is super buggy.  I'm wondering if it is buggy on other Ubuntu distros

Comment: So it's not only me. I am glad to hear that. I also found out now that it makes colorful stripes appear on youtube videos. Hope they fix it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah.  This is bad.  It's basically unusable after update to 86.0.4240.75-1 .  Here's what mine looks like.  Note that there are only two Chrome windows open-- the one in the bottom right is a visual artifact, as is the portion of my desktop surrounding it-- those are actually being displayed as the contents of the second Chrome windows, which you can see the border of in the middle.  Unfortunately, I don't have time to wait for an update.  I need it to work *today*, so I can fix other people's issues.  Lovely.

[image: BAD CHROME BUGGY!]

Only way I know to triage until they fix it in a future update is to uninstall and install an older version.

I need it to work now, like *right* now, so downloaded closest stable version I could find, closed Chrome and uninstalled buggy version using Synaptic;  closed Synaptic, and installed older version (84.xxx).

This worked to squash the bug, at risk of recently known security exploits.  Yay!  Hopefully they'll have a patch soon.

Oh, yeah-- this is where I got the old version:
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Specifically, this one:
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/download-chrome.php?file=files%2F84.0.4147.135%2FChromeStandaloneSetup.exe

And this is where I found the reference to SlimJim:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408325/download-older-versions-of-google-chrome-for-linux

Comment: Yes, this I have the same.  Still no update however, and I can't even submit a bug report to chrome because it freezes while trying to open the bug report window ha!

Comment: Actually, turning off hardware acceleration and rebooting chrome seems to work.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The problem was especially serious when using Google Drive.

Comment: They didn't fix it in this last update. I figured it works almost fine without being fullscreen so I guess I can wait.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue.  For now I have gotten around it by disabling hardware acceleration.  Hopefully the bug is fixed soon.

Comment: As for 87.0.4280.66 version, the bug still happens, and this solution fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I also see this. When Chrome goes to fullscreen it either flickers or stops rendering new content. Things are fine only by exiting fullscreen. As a result fullscreen is basically not usable.

This seems to be an interaction between Chrome and 16.04, because I tried Chrome Dev (newer Chrome) and it still had the issue, and I just upgraded my machine from 16.04 to 18.04 and normal Chrome (same version that showed the issue on 16.04) works fine.

Comment: Interesting... if I user@onyx ~ $ cat /etc/issue, I'm on Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia .  My problem was not just in full-screen though, but maximized and "restored" windows as well, and if I minimized got even worse.  Worked okay, mostly, with only 1 window open, till I did the retrograde and been fine since.  I am sure they will have another update soon though, so not too worried about it.  Maybe they only tested on **.4 version?

Answer (score 0):

Turning off hardware acceleration fixes this for me.  Ubuntu 16.04.  Problem was only in full screen/maximized and I would get a normal screen refresh if my mouse passed over the title bar.  If you moved it quickly back and forth over the title bar, even video could look somewhat normal.

Hopefully a fix comes soon... totally hijacked my workflow.

Comment: Wokrs fine with hardware acceleration since version 89.0.4389.82